# insert div elements in proper order using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html markup that contains 3 div elements. First parent `.parent` and second child of first `.child` and `.child` could have 1 or more children i.e. `.children`. When I click on last '.children' in '.child' then it clones that particular `.children` and appends after the clicked `.children`. So far ok. During this process, every row contains a fixed number of `.children`. I want that in the first row there should 3 `.children` then in second row 2 `.children` and in the third row 1 `.children`. And it starts over from row 4.

How can I achieve this?

Below is my code

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div id="1" class="children">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('body').on('click', '.children', function (e) {
    var clone = $(this).clone();

    $(this).after(clone);
});
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TM38x/)

Comment: Even though very well-presented, this still reads like a coding request. Where are you stuck? What *specific* issue are you having building a solution?

Comment: `<head>` inside `<div>` ?

Comment: @JohnB: OP probably meant [`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element), but that just begs the question, where is the [sectioning content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) or [sectioning root](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sectioning-root) it's meant to be associated with...

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here's an Example : For selecting nth child
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div > span").css("background-color","yellow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>    

<h2>What will $("div > span") select?</h2>

<h4>This div element has two direct child elements, p and span:</h4>
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span>This is a text inside a span.</span>
</div>

<h4>This div element has one direct child element, p:</h4>
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
<p>This is a paragraph. <span>This is a span element, inside the paragraph.</span></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a closure:

```
var rowLength = 3;
var nItemsInRow = 1;

$('body').on('click', '.children', function (e) {
    var clone = $(this).clone().removeClass('box-border');

    if (rowLength === nItemsInRow) {
       /* insert line break */
       /* ... */
       /* insert clone */
       /* ... */

       // now update counters
       --rowLength; if (rowLength === 0) rowLength = 3;
       nItemsInRow = 1;
    } else {
       $(this).after(clone);
       ++nItemsInRow;
    }

});
```

Comment: This code does not work in my case. This will also have delete method which will delete upon clicking `.children`. After deleting, the format of all these `.children` should remain in tact.